# Reducing duplicate querys in my laravel app

Tags: php, laravel

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;

class PermissionController extends Controller {

    public function set_permission(Request $request)
    {

        $id = $request['roleId'];

        $role = Role::findById($id);


        $all_permissions = $request['checkedId'];


        $role->syncPermissions();


        foreach ($all_permissions as $per)
        {

            $role->givePermissionTo($per);

        }
    }

}
```

I am using spatie-permission-package in my laravel app. The app offers the functionality so that admin can manually give specific permission to a specific rule. The code snippet has been added. It works fine but the problem is it is executing a lot more queries. how can need I reduce this redundant or duplicate queries.

[Here is a image for my queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI6Ju.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to sync empty permissions then assign them in foreach loop, you already have all permission ids passed in request, so just sync them

```
$role->syncPermissions($all_permissions);
// you don't need foreach loop here any more
```

Comment: This is what I needed.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping the permissions you can do the following.

```
$role->givePermissionTo($all_permissions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I am seeing on https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/advanced-usage/seeding/, I believe `$role->givePermissionTo()` can accept an array of permissions as well as a single permission.

Do things work as expected if you change

```
   foreach ($all_permissions as $per)
        {
            $role->givePermissionTo($per);
        }
```

to

```
$role->givePermissionTo($all_permissions);
```

?

Comment: Yes you can pass an array to givePermissionTo method but it won't detach other permissions so if role has permissions 1 and 2 and you run givePermissionTo([2,3]) now the role will have permissions 1,2,3,4